# Distance between two points on 3D Triangular Mesh Manifold

Tags: algorithms, graphs, computational-geometry, graphics

I'm working on my bachelor thesis (on Computer Science) and right now I'm having a problem about finding shortest path between two points on 3D triangular mesh that is manifold. I already read about [MMP](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Emount/Papers/mmp-sicomp-87.pdf), but which computes distance function $d(x)$  between given point and vertex $x$ on mesh.

I got to know that the problem I'm solving is named Geodesics but What I really couldn't find is some good algorithm which uses A* for finding shortest path between two given points on two given vertices.

I 'invented' also algorithm which uses A* by using Euclidian Distance Heuristics and correction after finding new Point on any Edge..
I also have edges saved in half-edge structure.

So my main idea is this:

1. We will find closest edge by A* algorithm and find on this edge point with minimalizing function $f(x) + g(x)$ where $f$ is our current distance and $g$ is heuristics(euclidean distance)
2. Everytime we find new edge, we will unfold current mesh and find closest path to our starting point

So now my questions:

- Do you know some research paper which talks about this problem ??
- Why nobody wrote about algorithm that uses A* ??
- What are your opinions about algorithm I proposed ?

Comment: Do you mean the shortest distance following the edges vertex by vertex, or the true geodesic distance (assuming a polyhedral surface) ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust True geodesic distance, Shortest distance following edges would be quite easily done by A* Pathfinding..

Comment: Ok, I agree with your method. Maybe you can replace the Euclidean distance heuristic precisely by using the edge-following distance.

Comment: @YvesDaoust well If I use edge-following heuristics, then the heuristic is no longer admissible (estimated distance is not lower or equal to real distance)